# Inferring Type of NonEmptyList(String, List[Nothing])?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Experimenting with [scalaz.NonEmptyList](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/NonEmptyList.scala), I tried:

```
scala> import scalaz.NonEmptyList
import scalaz.NonEmptyList

scala> NonEmptyList("5", Nil)
res0: scalaz.NonEmptyList[java.io.Serializable] = NonEmptyList(5, List())
```

I mistakenly thought that `List` was the second argument to `NonEmptyList#apply` (it's actually [varargs](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/NonEmptyList.scala#L121)).

But, why does `java.io.Serializable` show up as the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've constructed a list with two items, a `String` and a `Nil`.  So the type of that list is `NonEmptyList[A]`, where `A` is the lowest common supertype of *both* `String` and `Nil`, which is the type `Serializable`.  Btw: the same thing happens with scala's normal List: `List("5",Nil)`